# How to filter by NULL with ra-data-hasura

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, hasura

I'm trying to make a filter for react admin using ra-data-hasura as the dataProvider.

If I simply try and add `{foreign_id: {_is_null: true}}` I get many errors as it resolves into `{ foreign_id: _eq: { {_is_null: true} } }`. Using `{foreign_id: null}` also fails as that appears to be the default value.

What's the best way to get my `List` to show only rows where a column is either `NULL` or `not null`?

I'm using Postgres as my database if that matters.

Comment: This seems like it should be core functionality supported by `ra-data-hasura` I'd recommend opening an issue there and seeing if they'll add official support for this

Comment: > I get many errors  . Which exactly errors? `foreing_id` is a value for foreign key in another table? If so - than it would be better to show structures of your tables and graphql-query that leads to "many errors"

Answer (score 3):

There is an undocumented `hasura-raw-query`, which should help you here.

```
...
<List
...
filter={{
  foreign_id: {
    format: "hasura-raw-query",
    value: { __is_null: true },
  },
}}
>
...
```

Comment: this should be an accepted answer